# Converting XML to PDF

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, pdf-generation

i am a real new guy in java and was wondering if someone could explain me steps on how to convert xml to pdf. i tried xmlworker but couldnt implement it. I need to convert it for a school project so the please help

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you trying to put the xml arranged in the pdf? If you just want the exact same formatting as a xml file in a pdf you can just read the entire xml in as a string and then output to a pdf using a  [free library online such as this.](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Comment: could you explain me through a sample code. I dont think the arrangement matter, besides i can have xslt file handling that